# ¿Es posible enviar un json a un web service con volley?

Tags: java, android, webservice, android-volley

He estado leyendo y todo lo que me aparece es recibir respuesta del servidor y enviarle datos a este por parámetros dentro de la URL. Lo que me gustaría saber es  si existe la  posibilidad que desde mi app Android envié un json a mi web service para que este lo obtenga y reciba los datos, a diferencia de parámetros por la URL.

Utilizo volley como librería para gestionar las respuesta del web service.

Comment: revisa por aqui, creo que es la misma pregunta
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346786/json-on-android-serialization

Comment: gracias pero no es lo que busco.

Comment: osea que puedes enviar para metros por metodo get y post

Comment: hasta ahora recibo json del web service y envio mis datos por la url, solo quiero saber si es posible enviarlos de otro modo por ejemplo otro json pero que lo envie yo desde mi app al web service. Todo lo otro lo se manejar.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = "http://httpbin.org/post";
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
    new Response.Listener<String>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // response
            Log.d("Response", response);
        }
    }, 
    new Response.ErrorListener() 
    {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             // error
             Log.d("Error.Response", response);
       }
    }
) {     
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
    {  
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
            params.put("json", "{\"0\":\"valor1\",\"1\":\"valor2\",\"2\":\"valor3\",\"3\":\"valor4\"}");
            params.put("json2", (new JSONObject("{\"0\":\"valor1\",\"1\":\"valor2\",\"2\":\"valor3\",\"3\":\"valor4\"}")).toString());
            return params;  
    }
};
```

Intenta con ese y lo conviertes a un array en el web service que me imagino que tienes control sobre el; a lo que me refiero en el parametro post "json2" es que tambien podrias crear un json en la santaxis de java y convertila a String